# R started using 20 GB of memory spontaneously

Tags: r, memory, memory-management

I have been "setting up" a new project in R, i.e. copying bits of code together, I have run almost nothing and got an error when opening the project today:

```
WARNING: Failed to restore workspace from 'mywd/RData'
Reason: cannot allocate vector of size 172 Kb
```

[image: Screenshot of my Environment]

Can anyone explain where this is coming from, I've tried:

```
rm(list=ls(all=T))

gc()
```

which has reduced the memory usage to 17.88 GB, but that still seems excessive...

**update**

I closed RStudio and reopened it and my memory usage (without any loaded libraries or data) had reduced to 858 MB. I'm still confused about *why* this happened and what to do if it happens again.

**update2**
packages used... and YES, I *need* all of them.

###### tables

library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
library(readr)
library(data.table)
library(plyr)

###### taxonomy

library(Taxonstand)

###### database

library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(dbplyr)
library(knitr)

###### spatial

library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
library(rangeBuilder)
library(geosphere)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(vegan)

###### graphics

library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(broom)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggmcmc)
library(ggforce)
library(Hmisc)
library(cowplot)
library(ggpmisc)
library(gtable)
library(egg)

###### Bayes

library(R2WinBUGS)
library(runjags)

library(R2jags)
library(rjags)
library(dclone)

###### Modelling

library(psych)
library(betareg)
library(coda)

Comment: Hi, do you have any .Rprofile or .RData loaded when you start ? Also, can you give the list of packages loaded in this session  (`loadedNamespaces()`) ?

Comment: updated my question... no packages loaded on startup!

Comment: Well, still 800MB is kind of huge. It's not easily reproducible, I don't know how to understand what happened.

Comment: Unfortunately, showing what the RStudio pane lists for objects in the environment is inconclusive, as there are at least two other "places" to store objects: dot-names (e.g., `.varname <- 1` will not show); and within package namespaces. It would likely be helpful to know what packages you were using the last time with R/RStudio such that the memory bloomed.